# How to change a number written in a string form to an integer number

Tags: java

This is the code which I thought is supposed to work but it just returns garbage in the array I think and I've been trying to fix it but I can't find the error.

Thought the code is simple initially I want to input a string which has
written numbers and return those numbers as digits like : "two one nine six eight one six four six zero", "2196816460"

```java
private static final String[] numNames = {"zero",
                                          "one",
                                          "two",
                                          "three",
                                          "four",
                                          "five",
                                          "six",
                                          "seven",
                                          "eight",
                                          "nine",};
private static final char[] nums = {'0',
                                    '1',
                                    '2',
                                    '3',
                                    '4',
                                    '5',
                                    '6',
                                    '7',
                                    '8',
                                    '9',};

public static String getPhoneNumber(String s) {
    int k = 0;
    int z = 0;
    char [] chararray3 = new char [10];
    char [] chararray = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chararray.length; i++){
        if (chararray[i] == ' '){
            char [] chararray2 = new char[i-k-1];
            for (int j = 0; j < i - k; j++){
                chararray2 [j] = chararray[k]; 
                k++;
            }
            k++;
            for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++){
                if (chararray2.toString() == numNames[x]){
                    chararray3 [z] = nums[x];
                    z++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return chararray3.toString();
}
```

Comment: What does the output look like? I think you want to return `String.valueOf(chararray3);`

Comment: You might want to vote on the answers that helped you to reward people's effort, and pick one as the best answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. First issue is that `[].toString()` doesn't display the content of it, you need

   ```
   Arrays.toString(chararray3)
   ```
2. Then, your condition to do things in the loop is `if (chararray[i] == ' ')`, as there is no space, nothing execute, in fact, you are just creating an empty array, then return it, no more.
3. Your code is quite complex, and can't see how to "fix" it, so I propose a simpler way

   - Build a `String []` to save the names (can't be a `char[]`)
   - For each char of the input:

     - find their position in `nums`
     - save their corresponding value in `numNames` into your `result`

   ```
   public static String getPhoneNumber(String s) {

       char[] chararray = s.toCharArray();
       String[] result = new String[s.length()];

       for (int i = 0; i < chararray.length; i++) {
           if (chararray[i] != ' ') {
               for (int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++) {
                   if (chararray[i] == nums[j]) {
                       result[i] = numNames[j];
                       break;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       return Arrays.toString(result);
   }
   ```

---

Note that `"0"` can be to get value at index `0`, no need of `nums`

```
public static String getPhoneNumber(String s) {
    String[] values = s.split("");
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (!values[i].isEmpty()) {
            values[i] = numNames[Integer.parseInt(values[i])];
        }
    }
    return Arrays.toString(values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution using Stream API:

```java
public static String getPhoneNumber(String s){
   // decorate the array as a list (no copying involved!) so we can have indexOf
   final List<String> numNamesList = Arrays.asList(numNames);
   // Split, transform, join 
   return Arrays.stream(s.split("[\s]+"))
        .map(numNamesList::indexOf) // we assume all names exist!
        .map(index -> String.valueOf(nums[index]))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it was too complex indeed so I came up with a different code :

```
public static String getPhoneNumber(String s) {
    int k = 0;
    String nums = "";
    String[] StringArray = new String[10];
    char [] result = new char[10];
    for (int y = 0; y < StringArray.length; y++) {
        StringArray[y] = "";
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            k++;
            continue;
        }
        StringArray[k] += s.charAt(i);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (StringArray[i].equals(numNames[j])) {
                nums += numer[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return nums;
}
```